# I have a query about how asp.net manages datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question about how asp.net manages datasource

say if i bind country on first time page load

after that on every post back event it is not going to fetch data

in this case where is the data stored on page for dropdown country datasource

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindCountry();
    }
}

private void BindCountry()
{
    Business.CountryBAL objCountryBAL = new Business.CountryBAL();
    DataSet ds = objCountryBAL.GetAllCountry();
    drpCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    drpCountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
    drpCountry.DataSource = ds;
    drpCountry.DataBind();
    drpCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

Comment: not getting here what you are looking for. Are you talking about stateless part of asp.net ?

Comment: only first time i bind dropdown after that every at postback event i m not binding it.Still my dropdown has data so after first time from where dropdown get data

Comment: go MSDN and check ViewState  concepts of ASP.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET uses the concept of [View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that purpose:

`ViewState` is the method that the ASP.NET page framework uses to preserve page and control values between round trips.

The current state of the page and values that must be retained during postback are serialized into base64-encoded strings. By default, view state data is stored in the page in a hidden field and is encoded using base64 encoding.

ViewState has a major role in ASP.NET. Viewstate is a collection of name/value pairs, where control's and page itself store information that is persistent among web requests.

You need to better understand the [Control Execution Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)